# Computational issue for finding the JS divergence

Tags: probability, gaussian-mixture-distribution, kullback-leibler

I had two datasets with 144 points in 2 dimension then I used he sklearn library to fit the GMM and that fits well , I checked for the BIC values while fitting the model and chooses the model with low BIC value. After that I wanted to compute the JS divergence between the two gmms that we obtain and I used the followiing code

```
from scipy.stats import entropy

def js_divergence(gmm_p, gmm_q, n_samples=10000, eps=1e-5):
    X_p, _ = gmm_p.sample(n_samples)
    X_q, _ = gmm_q.sample(n_samples)
    X = np.vstack([X_p, X_q])

    p_pdf = np.exp(gmm_p.score_samples(X))
    q_pdf = np.exp(gmm_q.score_samples(X))

    # Adding a small constant for numerical stability
    p_pdf = np.clip(p_pdf, eps, 1 - eps)
    q_pdf = np.clip(q_pdf, eps, 1 - eps)
    
    m_pdf = 0.5 * (p_pdf + q_pdf)
    js_div = 0.5 * (entropy(p_pdf, m_pdf) + entropy(q_pdf, m_pdf))
    return js_div

js_div = js_divergence(gmm_first, gmm_second)
print("Jensen-Shannon Divergence:", js_div)
```

But the issue I am facing is that even when I take the data which are almost same then also sometime the JS values very high as we have  $0\leq JSD(p||q)\leq \ln(2)=0.693147$ so sometime I am getting the $0.6823$ which means both the pdfs are different but if my datasets is almost same then why JS value is high? And sometime after runing several times is shows values $0.0345$ like this which is acceptable! what mistake am I doing .